# image tab to fix for all devices

Tags: java, android

I want to set three image for create image tab.I set three image in activity_main.xml file.But it ok for only screen 5.0 inches.If over this,image is very small.How can I do that?Please help me kindly.

**this is activity_main.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:context=".SettingActivity"
        android:baselineAligned="false">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonHomeSelector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_home_config"
            android:onClick="imageButtonHomeSelector"

            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonLoginSelector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_login_config"
            android:onClick="imageButtonLoginSelector"

            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonSettingSelector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/setting_button_hover"
            android:onClick="imageButtonSettingSelector"

            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest two ways:
1) Use mipmap based images for all the 5 screen sizes (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi). And rather than

```
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonLoginSelector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_login_config"
        android:onClick="imageButtonLoginSelector"/>
```

try this:

```
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonLoginSelector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/icon_login_config"
        android:onClick="imageButtonLoginSelector"/>
```

which in-turn uses the respective image automatically based on screen size.

2) Use Vector Drawables as per this [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html)